# How should I fill these large cracks/voids in this brick porch?

Tags: brick, porch

Filling a few, I thought, small cracks on my porch jumped to the top of the to do list when I watched a chipmunk enter one of them yesterday.

He went in the crack in front of the step, the one I have a real closeup on. I don't know how far back that hole goes.

I'm thinking of just mixing up some concrete and then pushing it back as far as I can, maybe take gallon bag with a hole in the corner and push the product out as best I can. I'm guessing I probably need something else though, not regular concrete from an 80 pound bag? Possibly Polymeric sand or type O mortar without cement?

Suggestions welcome. I'm not wanting to rebuilt the steps or anything, just plug the holes. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ceramic fiber adhesive with squeezer? I don't think You need anything better for these. You may have problems with concrete to put it inside.

Comment: How big are the gaps?

Comment: Probably a half inch at the widest, and then several inches long.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard case of brickwork needing to be tuck-pointed.  You can find several sources on how to do it, but this one is nice:[This Old House](http://www.thisoldhouse.com/toh/article/0,,232787-2,00.html)